# Clarification about Quotient Ring Isomorphism Theorem for a Principal Ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

In Aluffi, he states the following ring isomorphism theorem:
$$\frac{R/(a)}{(\bar{b})} \cong R/(a,b)$$

His proof says that this follows from the first isomorphism theorem:
$$\frac{R/I}{J/I} \cong R/J$$

and the fact that:
$$(\bar{b}) \cong (a,b)/(a)$$

The last statement bothers me. By my reckoning
$$(\bar{b}) \cong (b)/(a) \cong (a,b)/(a)$$
because 
$$(\bar{b}) = Rb+(a) = Rb + Ra $$

What really is important here is that $(a,b)$ is the smallest ring that contains $(a)$  and $(b)$ which is required for the first isomorphism theorem.

And really we have, 
$$\frac{R/(a)}{(a) + (b)} \cong \frac{R}{(a) + (b)}$$ and $(a) + (b) = (a,b) \cong (\bar{b})$

My question is really whether or not my reasoning is correct here, and if Aluffi's statement is a bit misleading.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless we are given that $b \,|\, a$ so that $(a) \subseteq (b),$ we cannot say that $\overline{(b)} = (b) / (a).$ Particularly, the Second Isomorphism Theorem does not apply. We must really use that $\overline{(b)} = (b) + (a).$

Given ideals $I$ and $J$ of a ring $R,$ we claim that $$\frac{R/I}{J + I} \cong \frac{R}{I + J}.$$ Consider the map $\varphi : R \to (R / I) / (J + I)$ defined by $\varphi(r) = (r + I) + J + I = r + I + J.$ Given that $r = s,$ we have that $r - s = 0$ is an element of $I + J$ so that $r - s + I + J = 0 + I + J$ and $r + I + J = s + I + J.$ Consequently, it follows that $\varphi$ is well-defined. One can easily see that $\varphi$ is surjective with kernel $I + J,$ hence the claim holds by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

By identifying $I = (a)$ and $J = (b),$ the result you mention is established.

Comment: Why can't we say that $(\bar{b}) = (b)/(a)$? Is that not an ideal in $R/(a)$ if it doesn't include $(a)$. I get that the second isomorphism theorem doesn't apply, but is it a valid idea?

Comment: By the Correspondence Theorem (i.e., the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem), we have that $(b) / (a)$ is an ideal of $R / (a)$ if and only if $(b)$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $(a) \subseteq (b).$

Comment: Bad things can happen when we work with ideals that are disjoint. Consider the ideals $2 \mathbb Z$ and $3 \mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb Z$ for a worst-case scenario. By Bézout's Theorem, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $2x + 3y = 1$ (since $2$ and $3$ are coprime), hence we have that $2 \mathbb Z + 3 \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z.$ But this says precisely that $\overline{2 \mathbb Z} = 2 \mathbb Z + 3 \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z + 3 \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z,$ so the inclusion $2 \mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z$ is not preserved in this scenario.